# Flexscroll not working in show/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="right_tab_content_part1_s">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" id="classtabnew1" onclick="showHideDivforTabbingBeforeaward(1)">View Provider</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" id="classtabnew2" onclick="showHideDivforTabbingBeforeaward(2)">View Message</a>
    </div>

    <div style="display:block;" id="divtabnewBeforeaward1"></div>

    <div style="display:none;" id="divtabnewBeforeaward2"><div id="scroll2_msg" class="flexcroll"></div></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHideDivforTabbingBeforeaward(id)
    {
        for(j=1;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(id==j)
            {
                document.getElementById('divtabnewBeforeaward'+j).style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('classtabnew'+j).className = 'active';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('divtabnewBeforeaward'+j).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('classtabnew'+j).className = '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Flexscroll is not working, even when i use the enter `fleXenv.initByClass ("a-class-name-of-your-choice");` or `fleXenv.fleXcrollMain (yourDivElement);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this before closing the body tag:

```
<div id='flexcroll-init'></div>
```